# Error loading data to Druid

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, properties-file, druid

I am new to druid and trying to load data through local files.I have set up the nodes and zookeeper instance.I have tried this in Ubuntu 18.04 and is working  fine but i tried using it in lUbuntu and i see the error below:

```
2018-07-30T12:25:03,390 ERROR [main] io.druid.cli.CliPeon - Error when starting up.  Failing.
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
  at io.druid.guice.DruidProcessingModule.getIntermediateResultsPool(DruidProcessingModule.java:110) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> io.druid.guice.DruidProcessingModule)
  at io.druid.guice.DruidProcessingModule.getIntermediateResultsPool(DruidProcessingModule.java:110) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> io.druid.guice.DruidProcessingModule)
  while locating io.druid.collections.NonBlockingPool<java.nio.ByteBuffer> annotated with @io.druid.guice.annotations.Global()
    for the 2nd parameter of io.druid.query.groupby.GroupByQueryEngine.<init>(GroupByQueryEngine.java:81)
  at io.druid.guice.QueryRunnerFactoryModule.configure(QueryRunnerFactoryModule.java:88) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> io.druid.guice.QueryRunnerFactoryModule)
  while locating io.druid.query.groupby.GroupByQueryEngine
    for the 2nd parameter of io.druid.query.groupby.strategy.GroupByStrategyV1.<init>(GroupByStrategyV1.java:77)
  while locating io.druid.query.groupby.strategy.GroupByStrategyV1
    for the 2nd parameter of io.druid.query.groupby.strategy.GroupByStrategySelector.<init>(GroupByStrategySelector.java:43)
  while locating io.druid.query.groupby.strategy.GroupByStrategySelector
    for the 1st parameter of io.druid.query.groupby.GroupByQueryQueryToolChest.<init>(GroupByQueryQueryToolChest.java:104)
  at io.druid.guice.QueryToolChestModule.configure(QueryToolChestModule.java:101) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> io.druid.guice.QueryRunnerFactoryModule)
  while locating io.druid.query.groupby.GroupByQueryQueryToolChest
  while locating io.druid.query.QueryToolChest annotated with @com.google.inject.multibindings.Element(setName=,uniqueId=80, type=MAPBINDER, keyType=java.lang.Class<? extends io.druid.query.Query>)
  at io.druid.guice.DruidBinders.queryToolChestBinder(DruidBinders.java:45) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> io.druid.guice.QueryRunnerFactoryModule -> com.google.inject.multibindings.MapBinder$RealMapBinder)
  while locating java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends io.druid.query.Query>, io.druid.query.QueryToolChest>
    for the 1st parameter of io.druid.query.MapQueryToolChestWarehouse.<init>(MapQueryToolChestWarehouse.java:36)
  while locating io.druid.query.MapQueryToolChestWarehouse
  while locating io.druid.query.QueryToolChestWarehouse
    for the 1st parameter of io.druid.server.QueryLifecycleFactory.<init>(QueryLifecycleFactory.java:52)
  at io.druid.server.QueryLifecycleFactory.class(QueryLifecycleFactory.java:52)
  while locating io.druid.server.QueryLifecycleFactory
    for the 1st parameter of io.druid.server.QueryResource.<init>(QueryResource.java:113)
  at io.druid.server.QueryResource.class(QueryResource.java:78)
  while locating io.druid.server.QueryResource
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateMemory(Native Method)
    at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:127)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:311)
    at io.druid.offheap.OffheapBufferGenerator.get(OffheapBufferGenerator.java:53)
    at io.druid.offheap.OffheapBufferGenerator.get(OffheapBufferGenerator.java:29)
    at io.druid.collections.StupidPool.makeObjectWithHandler(StupidPool.java:112)
    at io.druid.collections.StupidPool.<init>(StupidPool.java:83)
    at io.druid.guice.DruidProcessingModule.getIntermediateResultsPool(DruidProcessingModule.java:115)
    at io.druid.guice.DruidProcessingModule$$FastClassByGuice$$8e266e5c.invoke(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod$FastClassProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:264)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod$Factory.provision(ProviderMethod.java:401)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod$Factory.get(ProviderMethod.java:376)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
```

I did try to increase the memory for middle manager assuming that is what causing the problem but that didn't work.
 Any help would be appreciated.
 Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to increase direct buffer memory. 
Refer: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/druid-user/clGruLMHAgU

In middle manager config you will find this option 
druid.indexer.runner.javaOpts set it to higher value -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=4g

Refer: druid.io/docs/latest/configuration/index.html

Answer (score 0):

you should modify the five process memory and restart